# I'm encountering an issue with re-purchasing a Google Play in-app item after refunding it for internal testing, how can I fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am facing an issue in my app's internal testing process while attempting to re-purchase a Google Play in-app item after refunding it. The app is currently published to the Internal Testing channel.

Initially, I successfully purchased the Google Play in-app item using the following code for testing purposes. However, when I refunded the order from the Google Play console and attempted to re-purchase the item for further testing, I encountered a warning message stating, "You have owned the item."

I understand that Google Play marks a purchased item as **PurchaseState.PURCHASED** even after refunding. Despite this, I need to find a way to programmatically re-purchase the Google Play in-app item for internal testing.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code where I process the purchases:

```
private fun processPurchases(purchasesResult: Set<Purchase>) {
    val validPurchases = HashSet<Purchase>(purchasesResult.size)
    purchasesResult.forEach { purchase ->
        if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (purchase.skus.contains(purchaseItem)) {  
                if (isSignatureValid(purchase)) {
                    validPurchases.add(purchase)
                }
            }
        } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Received a pending purchase of SKU: ${purchase.skus}")
            // Handle pending purchases, e.g., confirm with users about the pending
            // purchases, prompt them to complete it, etc.
            mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderPending)
        } else {
            mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderError)
        }
    }

    acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync(validPurchases.toList())
}
```

Comment: I think you should try purchase with other gmail account.
It also depends on you app business logic, if you configure your app in app products in such a way that each user can buy only one of that item, you should try use different account, if you haven't set such kind of restrictions it will be available to repurchase after a few hours or one day

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known issue in the Android in-app billing process after a refund. One way to deal with this is by consuming the purchase, which allows you to repurchase the item.

But, you could also modify you 'consumeAsync' method to actually consume the purchase. I assume that you have already initialized 'BillingClient' in your code before calling 'consumeAsync' method.

```
private fun processPurchases(purchasesResult: Set<Purchase>) 
{
    val validPurchases = HashSet<Purchase>(purchasesResult.size)
    purchasesResult.forEach { purchase ->
        if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) 
        {
            if (purchase.skus.contains(purchaseItem)) 
            {  
                if (isSignatureValid(purchase)) 
                {
                    validPurchases.add(purchase)
                    
                    // Check if the purchase needs to be consumed
                    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) 
                    {
                        consumePurchase(purchase)
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) 
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Received a pending purchase of SKU: ${purchase.skus}")
            // Handle pending purchases, e.g., confirm with users about the pending
            // purchases, prompt them to complete it, etc.
            mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderPending)
        } 
        else 
        {
            mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderError)
        }
    }
    acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync(validPurchases.toList())
}

private fun consumePurchase(purchase: Purchase) 
{
    val consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
        .build()

    billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams) 
    { 
        result, _ ->
        if (result.billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) 
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Purchase consumed successfully: ${purchase.skus}")
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to consume purchase: ${result.billingResult.debugMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```